# foreach mostra 1 arquivo espera depois limpa e mostra outro php

Tags: php, foreach

Tenho um `foreach` em `PHP` e ele mostra vários dados de um `XML`, porem neste `XML` possui 5 fotos e eu gostaria que o loop mostrasse a primeira foto, esperasse uns 10 segundos e depois mostrasse a segunda foto assim sucessivamente.
Segue o código que tenho:

```
<?php 
$link = "rss.xml"; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link) -> channel; 
foreach($xml -> item as $item){
echo "<div id='foto'>";
echo "<img id=\"foto\" src=".utf8_decode($item -> linkfoto)."><br /></div>";
break;
}
```

Desta forma com o `break;` ele mostra apenas a primeira foto, gostaria que tivesse um timer ou algo parecido para que aparecesse as outras fotos apos 5 segundos, apagando a primeira foto.

Comment: Há como realizar este procedimento com JAVA SCRIPT?

Answer (score 1):

O `break;` como mencionado ele impede a continuação do `foreach()`.

Uma alternativa é usar o `sleep()`, [veja o manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php).
Dessa forma estaria:

```
//...
foreach($xml -> item as $item){
echo "<div id='foto'>";
echo "<img id=\"foto\" src=".utf8_decode($item -> linkfoto)."><br /></div>";
sleep(10);
}
```

O valor inserido "dentro" da função é o tempo em segundos que deseja que ele espere, *mas isso não irá apagar a anterior*!

Nesse caso ele iria executar, esperar 10 segundos, executar novamente, esperar 10 segundos (...) até o fim do loop.

Entretanto, o PHP é processado no lado do servidor e por essa razão o cliente não a resposta até que o conteúdo fosse totalmente processado, ou seja iria haver o intervalo de 10 segundos mas todas as imagens seriam exibidas.

*Para que o cliente receba uma imagem a cada 10 segundos você tem algumas alterativas, as "vantagens" e "desvantagens" são relativas e apenas listei aquilo que lembro neste momento:*

- Usar o `sleep` com `flush()` e `ob_flush()` antes dele.

  > **Vantagem:** Não requer nenhuma outra alteração, apenas adicionar `flush(); ob_flush();` antes do `sleep();` e é mais seguro, garantido que sempre será a cada 10 segundos.
  >   
  >   **Desvantagem:** Alto tempo de carregamento de página, para SEO é péssimo, além do timeout (talvez) necessitar a ser alterado, o que não é bom, se possui limite de processos em andamento simultâneo essa solução é a pior. Além disso isso pode comprometer o carregamento de outros conteúdos da página. *Isso também não tem o capacidade de apagar a imagem antiga, sendo de qualquer forma necessário um Javascript para apagar a imagem anteriro a cada 10 segundos.*
- Usar "`AJAX`" para solicitar a cada 10 segundos uma nova imagem.

  > **Vantagem:** Reduz o tempo de carregamento consideravelmente, apenas tendo que criar uma página especifica para distribuir o conteúdo do loop, um a um.
  >   
  >   **Desvantagem:** É necessário criar uma outra 'página' para fornecer os dados e alterações na página que recebe. É menos seguro se não houver monitoramento ou verificação de tempo. Nesse caso o usuário pode ver o conteúdo antes dos 10 segundos. Além disso outros serviços, externos ao seu, podem usar tal conexão para coletar dados, se não houver limitação, de maneira mais fácil e rápida.
- Usar `Javascript` para exibir/mostrar o conteúdo a cada 10 segundos usando `CSS` em `display: none;`.

  > **Vantagem:** Requer pequenas alterações em seu código, reduz o tempo de carregamento consideravelmente.
  >   
  >   **Desvantagem:** Muito inseguro! Qualquer pessoa ao explorar o HTML da página (F12) poderá obter e visualizar o conteúdo ocultado, obviamente sem que aguarde os 10 segundos.

Existem outras soluções, isso vai depender da aplicação disso.